# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Source\Models\Post"

Tags: php, aplicação-web, classes

Não estou conseguindo instanciar o objeto, minha classe que fica dentro da Pasta source/Models

```php
<?php 

namespace Source\Models;

use CoffeeCode\DataLayer\DataLayer;

class Post extends DataLayer
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct("post",["title","description"]);
    }
}
```

Meu generate.php que fica na pasta raiz

```
<?php 

require __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Source\Models\Post;
use Faker\Provider\Image;
use Faker\Provider\Lorem;


for ($i=0; $i < 1; $i++) { 
    $post = New Post;
    $post->title = lorem::text(80);
    $post->cover = Image::image("/images", 300, 150);
    $post->description = Lorem::paragraph(2,true);

    var_dump($post);
}
```

meu arquivo .json

```
{
    "name": "rtsgo/blog",
    "description": "blog com pagina\u0000\u0000o",
    "require": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9",
        "coffeecode/datalayer": "^1.1",
        "coffeecode/paginator":"^1.0"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Renan Teotonio",
            "email": "renantn93@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Source\\":"source/"
        },
        "files": [
            "source/Config.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

minha estrutura de pastas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou usando o PHP 8, mas sempre dá erro

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Source\Models\Post" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\BLOG\generate.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\BLOG\generate.php on line 11

Comment: A classe *Post* não está sendo carregada antes de sua utilização

Comment: Importante melhorar sua pergunta, clicando em [edit].  De qual pasta vem esta classe `Post`? Está usando um autoload? composer? Forneça um [mcve]

Comment: Rodou `composer dump`?

Comment: como eu posso carregar a Classe antes?